# Facebook: "Help them see future posts by inviting them to like your Page."

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-notifications

I manage a Page on Facebook.

Every time someone Likes or Reacts to one of the Page's posts, we get one of the notifications:

> Help them see future posts by inviting them to like your Page.
> Help her see future posts by inviting her to like your Page.
> Help him see future posts by inviting him to like your Page.

---

[image: Help them see future posts by inviting them to like your Page.]

---

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with this notification.

There is **no button** to invite that person to Like the page. Why is that the message, when there's no visible Call To Action to actually invite the person?

## How do I "invite them to like the Page"?

Is there a way to invite that person *from the Page* to like the Page? We do not want to invite from our personal accounts. We are also not Friends with those people.

Is there any way to prevent these notifications? I do not want to invite people to like the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the notification. It will take you to your post.

**Click on the Likes number under your post.**

A window will pop up allowing you to Invite those people to Like your page.

[image: Invite to Like Page]

Comment: THANK YOU! Amazing how unintuitive this is and how I could never find that "Invite" button.